# wifi problem on ubuntu 16.04..!

Tags: networking, wireless, hp

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and and there is no sign of wi-fi, no on/off indicator

I have seen all the solutions on internet:
[image]
how to handle wi-fi problems, but none worked for me. I have HP Pavillion laptop.

What can I do?

output:
arjun@arjun-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network

0

```
8:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 0
    Region 0: Memory at b5500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: may you disable network manager from startup application

Comment: @MohamedSlama  there is no option for disabling network manager..

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/612ya.png

Comment: check this link to preview all application

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/192104/how-to-showhide-all-hidden-startup-applications-in-ubuntu-14.10/

Comment: sorry forget to attach link :)

Comment: The image clearly shows *Airplane Mode* is on. That suggests that the wireless switch or key combination on the laptop is set to disable wireless. Please find it and switch it.

Comment: @chili555 there is no wifi on / off button on my keyboard and i even tried by switching off my airplane mode..

Comment: @MohamedSlama i tried ur link, first of all it says unknown  command, which was stated in comments sections of ur provided link, then i modified that command omitting -i , command executed but no improvement seen at all. i still cant disable network manager..

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it

Comment: Please edit to include the output of `lspci`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, please check my output as asked by you..

Comment: You need to disable Secure boot in bios settings.

Comment: @Pilot6 my secure boot is disabled already..

Comment: what does `sudo modprobe wl` output?

Comment: try to execute this command `nm-applet`

Comment: @Pilot6      sudo modprobe wl gives output..=>modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

Comment: Secure Boot is on.

Comment: @Pilot6, I was facing the same problem, tried everything, turned secure boot off from bios and wifi started working. Thanks so much,  spent one full day on this. Laptop:Hp envy Ubuntu :16.04

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

this worked on ubuntu 14.06. test it and tell me if it worked for 16.04 too.

Answer (score -2):

I had faced the same issue in HP Pavillion laptop twice. Follow these steps:

1. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. Download [bcmwl-kernel-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/admin/bcmwl-kernel-source) in .deb format and then install through terminal. It may ask additional dependency, Download and install them separately.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the kernal can detect your hardware but lacks the driver software to make it work, so what you need to do is install the drivers for your wireless card.  I searched broadcom's website but I couldn't find the drivers for your wireless card but I found [another driver](https://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11) that is similar enough that it might work for you.  I'm not sure of your linux experience so I will just describe the whole process of installing it.

Download the file in the link
open up a terminal and type these commands

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xzvf name_of_file_goes_here
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: it says=>  make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

Comment: arjun@arjun-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads/src$ make                                          
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: My mistake, you don't need to `cd source` because the Makefile is one directory higher than that.  So skip the `cd source` and just do `make` then `sudo make install`.  I will edit my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: now it gives output as=>    install -D -m 755 wl.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless

Comment: what should i do now??